# How to avoid extra space character when slurping first expression

Tags: emacs, clojure, lisp, paredit

When using Paredit, I'm often confronted with the following (pipe char represents cursor):

```
(foo |bar baz)
```

I want to enclose `bar` in parens, so I use `paredit-wrap-around` (<kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>(</kbd>) to get this:

```
(foo (|bar) baz)
```

The same applies when I want to put bar inside a string instead, I can use <kbd>M</kbd>-<kbd>"</kbd> to get this:

```
(foo "|bar" baz)
```

However, Clojure also uses square brackets `[]` and curly braces `{}` for vectors, maps and sets. These don't appear to have a paredit 'wrap around' command. So in this case, e.g. to put bar into a vector, I typically use the <kbd>[</kbd> key to create a new vector:

```
(foo [|] bar baz)
```

followed by a `paredit-forward-slurp-sexp` (<kbd>C</kbd>-<kbd>→</kbd>), which results in:

```
(foo [| bar] baz)
```

I'd like to remove the space character that has been inserted before `bar`. Is this possible? Why does paredit retain a space char when going from an empty expression to one that contains one item? Shouldn't the first item added to an S-expression always be pushed right against the opening paren?

Comment: The assumption is probably that you're going to put something else at the head of the new list. I guess you could use the combination <kbd>C-<right></kbd> and <kbd>C-d</kbd>.

Comment: I must mention that `paredit-forward-slurp-sexp` from the newest paredit version 20130722.1324 (from MELPA) deletes the space character automatically. So you can press `[ C-)` to get `[bar]`. Also, `[` is bound to `paredit-open-square` which is a dwim command: selecting an expression and pressing `[` will wrap that expression into a vector. So pressing `C-M-SPC [` is another way. I use the latter way because it's more visual, and I can change my mind to select two expressions, and I get to keep the same habit between non-lisp buffers in autopair mode and lisp buffers in paredit mode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paredit has, for quite a while, had `paredit-wrap-curly` and `paredit-wrap-square`. If you want to use them, simply bind them to a likely-sounding key, and have at it. If you're using such an old version of paredit that these functions don't exist, you should upgrade (but I don't think you are, since the slurp commands work with them).

Answer (score 1):

The latest development version of paredit binds `M-[` to `paredit-wrap-square` which does exactly what you want.  Emacs already binds `M-{` is to `backward-paragraph`, but if you don't ever use that, you could customize paredit to shadow it:

```
(eval-after-load 'paredit
  '(progn
     (define-key paredit-mode-map (kbd "M-{") 'paredit-wrap-curly)))
```

If you want to delete all space around the point, you can always type `M-\` for `delete-horizontal-space`.